# Memorable combinations for Sargent mechanical combination locks

Tags: clojure

I have a safe with a manual combination lock that I periodically change the combination to. I like to use a combination that's easy for me to remember, so I thought I'd write a quick Clojure program to make it easier to pick a new combination.

Note: When I say "combination" in this write-up it means the numbers used to open the lock, not a mathematical combination.

**Rules for selecting a new combination:**

The rules for choosing combinations are in the Operating/Changing Instructions for the lock (see ["Selecting A New Combination"](http://www.sargentandgreenleaf.com/pdf/book_mech_locks.pdf)) but I'll repeat them here:

Observing the following rules will help you select a new combination which is secure and which will optimize the design strengths of your Sargent & Greenleaf lock.

1. Do not select numbers which all end in “0” and “5.” An example of a poor combination is: "50 – 15 – 30." An example
   of a good combination is: "52 – 15 – 37."
2. Do not select numbers in an ascending or descending sequence. An example of a poor combination is: "22 – 41 –
   68." An example of a good combination is: "22 – 68 – 41."
3. Leave at least a ten number margin between adjacent numbers of the combination. An example of a poor combination is:
   "41 – 39 – 66." An example of a good combination is: "41 – 30 – 66."
4. Do not use a number between 95 and 99 or between 0 and 20 for the third (or last) number of the combination. This
   can cause a condition which will inhibit the mechanism from locking correctly.

**English words:**

It's easier for me to remember an English word than a random sequence of numbers, so I thought I would get some help from a dictionary. I want all the six-character words in English that, when each character is mapped to a digit in the combination using the telephone keypad, fulfill the rules for selecting combinations. For example, "benign" is 23-64-46.

I found a text file listing over 355,000 words in the English language [here](https://github.com/nelsonic/english-words), and used a little unix shell magic to pull out all the six-character words into a separate file:

```
$ cat words.txt | grep "^[a-z]\{6\}$" > six-character-words.txt
```

**Approach:**

I considered two approaches.

The first approach (which I rejected) was to check every six-digit permutation for the ones that make an English word when mapped to letters using the telephone keypad, *and* that conform to the rules for selecting a combination. There are 8 choices for each digit (2-9 since 0 and 1 don't map to a character on the telephone keypad) and six digits per combination, so that's 8^6=262144 permutations. It's worse than that, because each digit represents 3 or 4 characters so for each permutation you have to check at least 3^6=729 permutations of characters (actually more because 7 and 9 map to 4 characters). This is getting really expensive.

The second approach (which I used) was to check each six-character English word by converting it to a combination and validating the combination using the rules from the manual. There are only about 28,000 six-character English words.

**Code:**

Please critique my code! Obviously I'm interested in fixing any bugs, but I'm also always looking for ways to be clearer, more idiomatic, more efficient, etc.

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)

(defn abs [n] (max n (- n)))

(defn keypad-numbers [word]
  "Generates a vector of digits from the letters in a word using the standard telephone keypad mapping of numbers and letters"
  (let [keypad {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2
                :d 3 :e 3 :f 3
                :g 4 :h 4 :i 4
                :j 5 :k 5 :l 5
                :m 6 :n 6 :o 6
                :p 7 :q 7 :r 7 :s 7
                :t 8 :u 8 :v 8
                :w 9 :x 9 :y 9 :z 9 }]
    (vec (map keypad (map keyword (map str (seq word)))))))

(defn combo-numbers [combo-digits]
  "Generates a vector of combination numbers from a vector of combination digits"
  (let [a (+ (* 10 (combo-digits 0)) (combo-digits 1))
        b (+ (* 10 (combo-digits 2)) (combo-digits 3))
        c (+ (* 10 (combo-digits 4)) (combo-digits 5))]
    [a b c]))

(defn all-end-with? [numbers combo-digits]
  "Checks if the last digit of the combination's numbers all end with one of the provided numbers"
  (let [a (combo-digits 1)
        b (combo-digits 3)
        c (combo-digits 5)]
    (and
        (not (nil? (some #(= a % ) numbers)))
        (not (nil? (some #(= b % ) numbers)))
        (not (nil? (some #(= c % ) numbers))))))

(defn ascending? [combo-digits]
  "Checks if the numbers in the combination are ascending (e.g. 23 56 72)"
  (let [nums (combo-numbers combo-digits)]
    (and (> (nums 2) (nums 1)) (> (nums 1) (nums 0)))))

(defn descending? [combo-digits]
  "Checks if the numbers in the combination are descending (e.g. 72 56 23)"
  (let [nums (combo-numbers combo-digits)]
    (and (< (nums 2) (nums 1)) (< (nums 1) (nums 0)))))

(defn has-margin? [margin combo-digits]
  "Checks if the numbers in the combination are separated by a margin"
  (let [nums (combo-numbers combo-digits)]
    (and (> (abs (- (nums 0) (nums 1))) margin)
         (> (abs (- (nums 1) (nums 2))) margin))))

(defn taboo-last-number? [combo-digits]
  "Checks if the last number in the combination is between 95 and 99, or 0 and 20"
  (let [nums (combo-numbers combo-digits)]
    (or
      (and (>= (nums 2) 0) (<= (nums 2) 20))
      (and (>= (nums 2) 95) (<= (nums 2) 99)))))

(defn valid-combination? [combo-digits]
  (and (not (all-end-with? [0 5] combo-digits))
       (not (ascending? combo-digits))
       (not (descending? combo-digits))
       (has-margin? 10 combo-digits)
       (not (taboo-last-number? combo-digits))))

(defn with-lines [fname fun]
  "Executes a function for each line in a file"
  (with-open [rdr (reader fname)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)] (fun line))))

(with-lines
  "/home/erturne/nas/Development/sargent_combination/six-character-words.txt"
  (fn [line]
    (let [combo-digits (keypad-numbers line)]
      (if (valid-combination? combo-digits)
        (let [nums (combo-numbers combo-digits)]
            (println (str line " - " (format "%s-%s-%s"
                                             (nums 0)
                                             (nums 1)
                                             (nums 2)))))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would

1. Calculate the combination-numbers in `valid-combination` and send these numbers to the separate checking-functions instead of the `combination-digits`
2. Remove the assertion that the combination consists of 3 numbers as much as possible.
3. Exploit the fact that `<` and `>` may take more than 2 arguments.
4. Exploit the fact that a combination number may never be `< 0` or `> 99`

The modified code then becomes:

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)

(defn abs [n] (max n (- n)))

(defn keypad-numbers [word]
  "Generates a vector of digits from the letters in a word using the standard telephone keypad mapping of numbers and letters"
  (let [keypad {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2
                :d 3 :e 3 :f 3
                :g 4 :h 4 :i 4
                :j 5 :k 5 :l 5
                :m 6 :n 6 :o 6
                :p 7 :q 7 :r 7 :s 7
                :t 8 :u 8 :v 8
                :w 9 :x 9 :y 9 :z 9 }]
    (vec (map keypad (map keyword (map str (seq word)))))))

(defn combo-numbers [combo-digits]
  "Generates a vector of combination numbers from a vector of combination digits"
  (map (fn [[tens ones]] (+ (* 10 tens) ones))
       (partition 2 combo-digits)))

(defn ascending? [combo-numbers]
  "Checks if the numbers in the combination are ascending (e.g. 23 56 72)"
  (apply < combo-numbers))

(defn descending? [combo-numbers]
  "Checks if the numbers in the combination are descending (e.g. 72 56 23)"
  (apply > combo-numbers))

(defn all-end-with? [numbers combo-numbers]
  "Checks if the last digit of the combination's numbers all end with one of the provided numbers"
  (every? identity  ; this is a working alternative to (reduce and ...)
          (map (fn [number] (some #(= (mod number 10) %) numbers))
               combo-numbers)))

(defn has-margin? [margin combo-numbers]
  "Checks if the numbers in the combination are separated by a margin"
  (every? identity
          (map (fn [[n1 n2]] (> (abs (- n1 n2)) margin))
               (partition 2 1 combo-numbers))))

(defn taboo-last-number? [combo-numbers]
  "Checks if the last number in the combination is not between 20 and 95"
  (let [last-number (last combo-numbers)]
    (or (<= last-number 20)
        (>= last-number 95))))

(defn valid-combination? [combo-digits]
  "Check that combo-digits can form a good combination"
  (let [combo-numbers (combo-numbers combo-digits)]
    (and 
       (not (all-end-with? [0 5] combo-numbers))
       (not (ascending? combo-numbers))
       (not (descending? combo-numbers))
       (has-margin? 10 combo-numbers)
       (not (taboo-last-number? combo-numbers)))))

(defn with-lines [fname fun]
  "Executes a function for each line in a file"
  (with-open [rdr (reader fname)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)] (fun line))))

(with-lines
  "/home/erturne/nas/Development/sargent_combination/six-character-words.txt"
  (fn [line]
    (let [combo-digits (keypad-numbers line)]
      (if (valid-combination? combo-digits)
        (let [nums (combo-numbers combo-digits)]
            (println (str line " - " (format "%s-%s-%s"
                                             (nums 0)
                                             (nums 1)
                                             (nums 2)))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Function `keypad-numbers`

First of all **do not call `seq` on a collection before passing it to `map`**, `map` already does it.

This is too verbose, and too nested:

```
(vec (map keypad (map keyword (map str word))))
```

Another way of writing this:

```
(vec (map (comp keypad keyword str) word))
```

Yet another:

```
(->> word
  (map str)
  (map keyword)
  (map keypad)
  vec)
```

Of course you can use characters as map keys, so this is much less verbose and also much easier to understand:

```
(defn keypad-numbers [word]
  "Generates a vector of digits from the letters in a word using the standard telephone keypad mapping of numbers and letters"
  (let [keypad {\a 2 \b 2 \c 2
                \d 3 \e 3 \f 3
                \g 4 \h 4 \i 4
                \j 5 \k 5 \l 5
                \m 6 \n 6 \o 6
                \p 7 \q 7 \r 7 \s 7
                \t 8 \u 8 \v 8
                \w 9 \x 9 \y 9 \z 9 }]
    (vec (map keypad word))))
```

### Function `combo-numbers`

There is copy pasted code here:

```
(defn combo-numbers [combo-digits]
  "Generates a vector of combination numbers from a vector of combination digits"
  (let [a (+ (* 10 (combo-digits 0)) (combo-digits 1))
        b (+ (* 10 (combo-digits 2)) (combo-digits 3))
        c (+ (* 10 (combo-digits 4)) (combo-digits 5))]
    [a b c]))
```

It could be written like this instead:

```
(defn combo-numbers' [combo-digits]
  "Generates a vector of combination numbers from a vector of combination digits"
  (->> combo-digits
    (partition 2)
    (map #(+ (* (first %) 10) (second %)))
    vec))
```

Note `combo-numbers'` does not require `combo-digits` to be a vector anymore. It also can handle any even sized collection. For odd sized collections it just ignores the last  element. Like in web-services, it is better to be lenient while accepting and strict when returning.

### Function `all-end-with?`

Here, also, copy/pasted code is present:

```
(defn all-end-with? [numbers combo-digits]
  "Checks if the last digit of the combination's numbers all end with one of the provided numbers"
  (let [a (combo-digits 1)
        b (combo-digits 3)
        c (combo-digits 5)]
    (and
        (not (nil? (some #(= a % ) numbers)))
        (not (nil? (some #(= b % ) numbers)))
        (not (nil? (some #(= c % ) numbers))))))
```

This could be written like this instead:

```
(defn all-end-with?' [numbers combo-digits]
  "Checks if the last digit of the combination's numbers all end with one of the provided numbers"
  (let [a (combo-digits 1)
        b (combo-digits 3)
        c (combo-digits 5)
        p (set numbers)]
    (every? p [a b c])))
```

Note, in clojure :

- `nil` is a falsy value.
- Sets are predicates, that test if they contain the passed parameter.

Another problem with `all-end-with?` has a misleading name. it would be better it was run on `combo-numbers` instead of `combo-digits`:

```
(defn all-end-with?'' [numbers combo-numbers]
  "Checks if the last digit of the combination's numbers all end with one of the provided numbers"
  (->> combo-numbers
    (map #(mod % 10))
    (every? (set numbers))))
```

Note the concordance between the doc string provided, and how the code reads now.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the original code in place in the question. Here's the updated version taking all the feedback into consideration:

```
(ns com.sargentandgreenleaf.combination
  (:use [clojure.java.io :only [reader]]
        [clojure.string :only [join]]))

(defn abs [n] (max n (- n)))

(defn keypad-numbers [word]
  "Generates a sequence of digits from the letters in a word using the standard telephone keypad mapping of numbers and letters"
  (let [keypad {\a 2 \b 2 \c 2
                \d 3 \e 3 \f 3
                \g 4 \h 4 \i 4
                \j 5 \k 5 \l 5
                \m 6 \n 6 \o 6
                \p 7 \q 7 \r 7 \s 7
                \t 8 \u 8 \v 8
                \w 9 \x 9 \y 9 \z 9 }]
    (map keypad word)))

(defn all-end-with? [numbers combo]
  "Checks if the last digit of the combination's numbers all end with one of the provided numbers"
  (let [last-numbers (map #(mod % 10) combo)
        s (set numbers)]
    (every? s last-numbers)))

(defn ascending? [combo]
  "Checks if the numbers in the combination are ascending (e.g. 23 56 72)"
  (apply < combo))

(defn descending? [combo]
  "Checks if the numbers in the combination are descending (e.g. 72 56 23)"
  (apply > combo))

(defn has-margin? [margin combo]
  "Checks if the numbers in the combination are separated by a margin"
  (every? (fn [[n1 n2]] (> (abs (- n1 n2)) margin))
    (partition 2 1 combo)))

(defn taboo-last-number? [combo]
  "Checks if the last number in the combination is between 95 and 99, or 0 and 20"
  (let [last-number (last combo)]
    (or (<= last-number 20)
        (>= last-number 95))))

(defn valid-combination? [combo]
  "Checks that a combination is valid according to the rules in http://www.sargentandgreenleaf.com/pdf/book_mech_locks.pdf"
  (and (not (all-end-with? [0 5] combo))
       (not (ascending? combo))
       (not (descending? combo))
       (has-margin? 10 combo)
       (not (taboo-last-number? combo))))

(defn combo-numbers [combo-digits]
  "Generates a sequence of combination numbers from a collection of combination digits"
  (map (fn [[tens ones]] (+ (* 10 tens) ones))
    (partition 2 combo-digits)))

(defn run [fname]
  (with-open [rdr (reader fname)]
    (doseq [word (line-seq rdr)]
      (let [combo (combo-numbers (keypad-digits word))]
        (if (valid-combination? combo)
          (println (str word " - " (join "-" combo))))))))

(run  "./six-character-words.txt")
```

Comment: Actually earlier version of `with-lines` is more readable. You can use let destructuring, instead to remove redundancy. And in the current version You can write just `(str line " - " (clojure.string/join "-" combo))` instead. Also do not forget to check my answer;)

Comment: Just updated my code to include your feedback. Thanks for the help!